# pagination like twitter with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, kaminari

Now I am trying to set up ajax reloading pagination system like twitter with kaminari. But I got an error message. Could you give some advice?

☆error message

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /members
undefined method `paginates_per' for #<Class:0x007f8afcd2e428>
```

☆member.rb

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope :order => 'created_at DESC'
  paginates_per 15

end
```

☆index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>
<p>※登録されているユーザーのリストです。</p>

      <div class= "form_index">
        <%= form_tag({:action=>"index"}, {:method=>"get"}) do %>
         <div class="from_field_index">
          <%= text_field_tag 'name' %>
         <%= submit_tag '名前検索' %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>

<div id="lists">
   <%= render 'index' %>
</div>  

 <%= paginate @members, remote: ture %>
```

☆_index.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>写真</th>
    <th>名前</th>
    <th>分野</th>
    <th>場所</th>
    <th>経験</th>
     <th>Follow</th>
    <%# if Member.find(session[:user_id]).admin %>
    <%# end %>
  </tr>
<% @members.each do |member| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <% if member.provider %>
        <%=image_tag member.image ,:size=>'30x30'%>
     <% elsif member.avatar_file_name %> 
        <%= image_tag member.avatar.url(:thumb), :width =>'30px', :height =>'30px' %>
     <% else %> 
        <%= image_tag "love.png", :size=>'30x30'  %>  
     <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="/members/<%= member.id %>"><%= member.name %></a>
       <% if member.provider == "facebook" %>
           <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/<%=member.uid %>"> <%=image_tag "fb.png" ,:size=>'20x20'%>  </a>
        <% elsif member.provider == "twitter" %>
           <a target="_blank" href="http://www.twitter.com/<%=member.name %>"> <%=image_tag "twitter.png" ,:size=>'20x20'%>  </a>
       <% end %>
    </td>

    <td><%= member.field %></td>
    <td>
         <% if member.url.present? %>
           <%=link_to member.place ,member.url ,:target=>["_blank"] %> 
         <% else %>
          <%= member.place %>
        <% end %>  
      </td>
      <td><%= member.experience %></td>
      <td>
        <div class="onoff">
            <% unless session[:user_id] == member.id %>    
                 <% if @Frids.include? member.id%>
                  <%= link_to'解除', {:controller => 'members', :action => 'index', :id =>
                  member.id}, class: "btn btn-midium btn-warning"%><br/>
                <% else %>
                   <%= link_to'follow', {:controller => 'members', :action => 'index', :id =>
                  member.id}, class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%><br/>
               <% end %>
             <% end %>  
         </div>
      <%#= member.friends.count %>
    </td>

     <% if Member.find(session[:user_id]).admin %>
         <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', member, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
     <% end %>

  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

☆index.js.erb

```
$('#lists').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'index', object: @members) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to do `bundle install` after putting it into your Gemfile and restart your server?